# Export embedded .ico to disk

Tags: c#, resources

How would I export an embedded .ico icon file that I have embedded in my Resources.resx? I found this one example, but I'm not sure what the targetAssembly part would be.

If anyone could give me some pointers here it would be very helpful.

```
public static void WriteResourceToFile(Assembly targetAssembly, string resourceName, string filepath)
    {

        using (Stream s = targetAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(targetAssembly.GetName().Name + "." + resourceName))
        {

            if (s == null)
            {

                throw new Exception("Cannot find embedded resource '" + resourceName + "'");

            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];

            s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            using (BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create)))
            {

                sw.Write(buffer);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: See my 2nd edit and check out the [Free E Books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Comment: Your Edit 2 needs a FileStream like Jason posted, not a string.

Comment: No, the `Properties.Resources.iconName.Save` method has 5 overloads. I did check this, you must have seen Jason's answer and thought that method only supports streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like (from your comments on Jeremy's answer) that you already have the Icon stored in your application properties. If that's the case, there's no need to manually look it up and parse it out of the executing assembly.

If you take a look at the [Icon Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.aspx) you'll see that it has a method called `Save(...)`. Bit convenient isn't it?

To save it to disk is as simple as opening a `FileStream` and calling `Save`.

In your case:

```
using (var fStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(userDir, "iconName.ico"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    Properties.Resources.iconName.Save(fStream);
}
```

Simple stuff, just read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I know it must frustrate you that I'm new to all this, but I'm trying to learn the best way I can. Do you think I didn't already spend hours on Google trying to find an answer before I posted here? It's easy when you know where to look.

Comment: I get that it can be frustrating, but most of the classes in C# are generally pretty well documented on the MSDN site. Just by browsing through the methods on the page `Save` should stand out as something you may want to look into. Then you can just google `save icon to disk C#` or something similar and voila.